# How do I send an event in a dfp template to notify when the creative has actually loaded?

Tags: ads, google-dfp

I have a leaderboard on my page delivered via DFP. I would like to capture an event that fires when the creative has finished rendering inside the iframe.

I am aware of

```
googletag.pubads().addEventListener("slotRenderEnded", function(){...});
```

but this is practically useless, it only fires to notify that the iframe has been put in place.

Is there a way to fix this in the ad templates in DFP?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this project: [DFP Events](https://github.com/mcountis/dfp-events).